# Short circuit protection for my voltage source

Tags: dc, short-circuit, voltage-source

Can someone suggest me some short circuit protection schematic? I have 12V DC source (1.2A max. output current) and I will use it in some amateur electronics projects, but I would like to add some short circuit protection (between voltage source on one side and load on other side). I found some schematics on web involving BJTs but I would like to see opinion of professionals here :)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked into a fuse?

Comment: I want some more sophisticated solution :)

Comment: And fuse, If I'm not mistaken, can't save some sensitive compontents, because of it's reaction time?

Comment: What components are you worried about? You can fry something with too much current no matter how well short-circuit protected the supply is.

Comment: @Nick Johnson, I mean components inside voltage source, I want to prevent damaging it in case of shorting it...

Comment: @hari A better solution would be to find a voltage source that won't be damaged by short-circuit, especially if it's short-lived. Most good supplies meet this criteria.

Comment: Can you clarify if you have designed the power supply yourself, or is it an off-the-shelf item? Many commercial power supplies can be shorted indefinitely. If off the shelf-please post link. If  home-made, post schematic. The best way to do it probably would be to put a current limiting circuit in series with the output. But the current limiting circuit will have some voltage drop. So ideally, you would take the output feedback voltage from AFTER the current limit circuit. But you can't do that without getting inside the supply.

Comment: @mkeith, it is some DC adapter I got with dsl modem few years ago. Maybe it has already current limiting inside it, but I would like to build such circuit myself :)

Comment: It probably does have current limiting inside it. Any "current source" circuit will limit the short circuit current. But as I said, it will also reduce the output voltage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most professional solution requires access to internals of the supply [so needs to be designed in it], specifically access its feedback pin/loop. See the application schematics for [LMP8646](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmp8646.pdf) for instance.

Since you probably don't have access to that with your DSL modem DC adapter (unless you open it and mod it, which requires good understanding of the mains-voltage safety issues), you'll have to use a pass element (BJT or FET) for the overcurrent comparator to shut off instead. Look at [LTC4361](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/436112fb.pdf) for the general idea; that one is for 5V though. I don't know an IC off the top of my head for 12V. Something probably exists. A [hotswap controller](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/2736) would also have this current limiting function, but may be overkill for what you need.